# Doing 'if statement' gives strange result in console

Tags: jquery, if-statement, global-variables

I'm doing an `if` statement using the presence of a global variable. The variable:

```
 _class = $('a').parent().closest('*[class]')[0].className;
```

In this case there is no parent and so there is no class. I would like to recieve this info in the console, so I did an `if` statement:

```
if ( _class !== undefined ) {

    console.log('has class');

}else{

    console.log('undefined');

}
```

In Chrome inspector I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined` and nothing else regarding my `if` statement. My question: what can I do to get rid of the error message and output my `if` statement? I tried it with `null` and `length` and so on, nothing seems to work.

Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qep8y/)

Comment: a tag didn't have parent

Comment: There is no `closest` to your parent, @Rajaparabhu's answer was right, someone/he deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for element existence before trying to get className property:

```
_class = $('a').parent().closest('*[class]').length ? $('a').parent().closest('*[class]')[0].className : undefined;
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you:) What a weird construct..never seen that before

Comment: @Youss For more on the ternary operator (`... ? ... : ...`) in JavaScript, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @Youss the expression is using a "ternarary operator" (the ? element). Very handy syntax used in a lot of languages.

Answer (score 4):

Try to handle that error,

```
 _class = $('a').parent().closest('*[class]')[0] || "NOPE";

 if (_class === "NOPE") {
     console.log('undefined');
 } else {
     if (_class.className !== undefined) {
         console.log('has class');
     } else {
         console.log('undefined');
     }
 }
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qep8y/2/)

Comment: But you were right with `.closest()`, that was important.

Comment: @ShaunakD Thanks for the encouragement.. :)

Comment: I liked your answer. +1.

Comment: But I'm still unclear why having $('a').parent().closest('*[class]')[0].className cause an error.

Comment: @C-link Because parent of `a` is `body`. There is no parent of body. so `closest` throws error.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with your global assignment: the code doesn't get as far as your if statement. You're trying to derive a property from a null reference -- that could be `parent` or the result of your `closest` call. You need to do some checking around that initial assignment.

Comment: I tried that and failed: `if (!$('a').parent().closest('*[class]')[0].className){ //do stuff` Do you have any pointers on this?

Comment: @Youss You need to first check that `$('a').parent().closest('*[class]')[0]` is defined before you attempt to access `$('a').parent().closest('*[class]')[0].className`. The problem is that you're essentially trying to do `undefined.className` which results in an error.

Comment: Yeah your testing is flawed -- you're 'chaining' attributes and if one in the middle is undefined, the code will fail. Follow @apsillers advice.

Comment: Thanks for you time, I understand now. Im going to accept A. Wolff anwser

Answer (score 2):

first check if you select at least an element

```
   elements = $('a').parent().closest('*[class]');

    if (elements.length > 0) {
       _class = elements[0].className; 
       if ( _class !== undefined ) {
          console.log('has class');
       }else{
          console.log('undefined');
       }
    }
    else {
       console.log('no element found');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you try to find className of jQuery Object. But className - it's method for DOM elements, which often returns with simple javascript method, for example getElementById and so.
If you work with jQuery Object, use jquery methods for it, and in this case methid .attr('class');